# Issue on Setting/Getting Global Variable in PHP

Tags: php

Why I am not able to get the `$somevar` on `getVar()`

I am getting this error while using `print "Somevar is ".  GLOBAL $somevar;`

> Line : 10 -- syntax error, unexpected 'GLOBAL' (T_GLOBAL)

and

> E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined variable: somevar -- at line 10

when using witout GLOBAL `print "Somevar is ". $somevar;`

```
<?php
   $somevar;

   function setVar() {
      GLOBAL $somevar;
      $somevar++;
   }

   function getVar() {
      print "Somevar is ".  GLOBAL $somevar;
   }
   setVar();
   getVar();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you have shown to us I see some issues on your code:

1. You have not assigned any value to $somevar
2. You have missed a $ sign at the beginning of the GLOBALS keyword (and you missed an S letter at the end)
3. $GLOBALS is a superglobal variable and it is actually an array - so to access the $somewar value you have to type something like this $GLOBALS['somevar']

I will provide you with an example of how to work with global variables

```
$name = 'John';

function getGlobalVarName() {
 return $GLOBALS['name'];
}

echo getGlobalVarName();
```

Read more about variable scope (global variables) here: [Variable Scope in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)